# A web browser used in mobile phones to be used on desktop

Tags: windows, gratis, web-browser, bandwidth

Web browser for mobile phones tend to use less bandwidth than desktop web browser. Also, they are generally small in size when install (or they can take up less space for those portable version).

So, are there any gratis web browser for mobile phones that can be used on desktop machine (Windows OS)? Or, in another words, are there software developer company that create web browsers that tend to use less bandwidth and take up less space?

Comment: An emulator could be a solution for taking less bandwidth, but it would take a lot of disk space. Maybe there are Firefox add-ons to mimick a mobile device (sending the appropriate HTTP headers to get mobile versions of websites), would that be OK?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, for me, it is generally ok, but unfortunately, my end-user are IT beginners, who do not know what is Firefox add-ons. They only know how to open a web browser and use google to search for what they want. They do not know how to configure the web browser. Also, most web site for desktop are very dynamic and bandwidth-hungry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Opera** has mobile browsers which are known for their bandwidth efficiency<sup>**1**</sup>. Targeting developers, *Opera* offers a "mobile emulator" which is [available for download here](http://www.opera.com/developer/mobile-emulator) – for Linux, Mac and Windows.

---

<sup>**1:** They do so by proxying all traffic via their servers, where content is optimized – e.g. images get compressed etc.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

With **Chrome** you can easily [Simulate Mobile Devices with Device Mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/) and test a given device (such as iPhone 6s, Nexus 5X or a customized screen size).

You can also [throttle the bandwidth](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/network-conditions) to simulate diferent download rates of a mobile connection (such as GPRS, 3G, 4G...) to test the performance of a Website.

[image]

These tools are generally used by Mobile- and Web-developers.